# Add noise to gradient photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, noise

Does anyone know how to add noise to a gradient on photoshop cs3 ?

Comment: This should not be asked here, SO is for programming questions. Refer to the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq for relevant questions. Should maybe be moved to doctype.

Comment: I guess you guys didn't get the question at all. Filter > Noise > Add noise works for solid colors but it DOES not work when you have a layer style applied.

Comment: you could also try using http://photo.stackexchange.com/ - its stackexchange site about photos.

Answer (score 4):

`Filter > Noise > Add Noise...`

EDIT: If it's on a layer style (good info to add), you can right click the FX button next to the layer, and select "Create Layers". This will split the gradient overlay onto its own layer. Then apply a noise filter to that layer.

Comment: Try to do that when you have a gradient. Really ?

Comment: I'm really not sure where you're going with this. I just tried it, it worked.

Comment: +1 Never know you could expand layer styles to layers, very nice trick!

Comment: sorry but completely wrong what you  wrote in your edit

Comment: Actually, no. I've done it myself, and did it prior to posting my edit, so I can say with 100% certainty that it works. 

Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

From your comment on SO I know you are using a layer style. **You should specify this as this is NOT the only way to get a gradient.**

A gradient layer style will be applied OVER the layer. Filter > Noise applies the noise to the layer which is then being covered by a layer style.

There are several ways to do this with a layer style, here are a couple:

- Create a new empty layer, then select
  both layers, right click and select "merge layers"
  this will rasterize your layer style.
  You can now add the noise filter
  directly to it.
- Add a layer mask, Layer>layer
  mask>reveal all. Then apply the noise
  filter to the layer mask.

There are plenty more ways, these are just the 2 that popped into my head at the moment.

Comment: Actually, I just checked kcoppock's edit and that is a better way than I had listed. But like I said, there are several ways.

Comment: Your way's good too, I actually thought about the layer mask trick. Only problem I was thinking was that any other layer effects (e.g. Drop Shadow, Outer Glow) would bleed into the areas left transparent by the layer mask. If it was just the gradient though, and a white background it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Helton Valentini,

i know its too late might be you got your answer, but try this if you need

first of all apply your gradient on the layer than convert it to smart object than apply noise from

Filter > Noise > Add Noise...

and for any other question related  to graphics photoshop please ask here [graphicdesign.stackexchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)  its completely dedicated to the design community