# gradient noise like this

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I tried a lot.. but couldn't create a noised gradient like the brown one in this picture:
http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/4082/screenshots/830063/bm3.png

What settings should I use? (in `Add Noise` panel)

(Note: the picture adapted from dribbble, created by [rockatee](http://dribbble.com/rockatee).

Comment: What setting should I use? Just try them all?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [Add noise to gradient photoshop](http://superuser.com/questions/219464/add-noise-to-gradient-photoshop).